# Angular Material - dropdown order items alphabetically

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a dropdown with user names. I would like to order it alphabetically. How can I achieve this?

```
<md-select formControlName="user" id="user" style="min-width: 200px;">
                <md-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.id">
                    {{user.displayName}}
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can build a custom `OrderBy` Pipe for this.

For example the below OrderBy Pipe will sort the *object array* by the `key` you passed to it with alphabetically or value based (order: **asc**):

```
@Pipe({name: 'OrderBy'})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTranform {
  transform(input: any, key: string) {
    if (!input) return [];

    return input.sort(function(itemA, itemB) {
      if (itemA[key] > itemB[key]) {
        return 1;
      } else (itemA[key] < itemB[key]) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  }
```

}

and in your template as below:

```
<md-option *ngFor="let user of users | OrderBy: 'id'" [value]="user.id">`
```

don't forget to add `OrderByPipe` to your `declarations` of `NgModule`.

**UPD:**

as answered by @DeborahK and angular appendix **[No FilterPipe or OrderByPipe](http://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)**(last part), `OrderBy` with a impure Pipe may cause performance problem, so here I'm providing an pure Pipe which means you can determine when to fire the OrderBy Pipe which is give the input Array a new instance or change the parameter transformed to the Pipe.

**[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/AaBETrTdnCvU9Ml74JVn?p=info)**.

Comment: There are potential performance issues with building an OrderBy pipe. From the docs: `The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself...If these performance and minification considerations don't apply to you, you can always create your own such pipes (similar to the FlyingHeroesPipe) or find them in the community.` See the appendix here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: @DeborahK I know that problem with performance. thah why here I'm providing a pure pipe and OP can determin when to fire the Pipe. If there are still any issues, please let me know and glad to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Consider sorting the set of users in the component class. Then it will be in order when its used in the ngFor.

If you can provide the component class code you are using to build/retrieve the users array, we could provide more specific suggestions for sorting it.

You can find the doc for the sort method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example

```
var fruit = ['cherries', 'apples', 'bananas'];
fruit.sort(); // ['apples', 'bananas', 'cherries']
```