# How to order mat-select alphabetically when options have conditional names

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have this mat-select that I want to order alphabetically.

```
 <mat-select [(ngModel)]="item" name="item" (selectionChange)="changeIdentificationOptions($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of itemss" [value]="item">
              {{ item.name ? item.name: item.identity}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

The name of the option displayed is conditional. Each item will have an optional name. If it does have a name then it will be used, otherwise the identity name will be used.

I've seen on SO that it is suggested to make a custom orderBy pipe something like this answer [Angular Material - dropdown order items alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921319/angular-material-dropdown-order-items-alphabetically)

But that sorts using a single key. I'm not very experienced in making custom pipes. How would this work for my case?

Comment: How did you use the accepted solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to create a pipe which can be used for entire project, like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({  name: 'orderBy' })
export class OrderrByPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {
        return records.sort(function(a, b){
            if(a[args.property] < b[args.property]){
                return -1 * args.direction;
            }
            else if( a[args.property] > b[args.property]){
                return 1 * args.direction;
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        });
    };
}
```

And then you can use it like:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of itemss | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction}"" [value]="item">
   {{ item.name ? item.name: item.identity}}
</mat-option>
```

Note: column=> any property, direction(1 or -1) => for ascending/descending

[For more detail see this](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1211/angular-2-search-and-sort-with-ngfor-repeater-with-example)

Answer (score -1):

The data should ideally be ordered alphabetically from the backend.

There is no 'orderBy' pipe for it because the Angular team believe it should be sorted already, as per the docs at https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please consider including some of the relevant info from your link in the space provided for an answer